# Assign text to textbox when usercontrol is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, user-controls, panel

I am building a program that is to generate some mathematical questions and then check and correct the answer given by the user.

I have a MainForm with a Panel where i add all my different UserControls. 
In my MainUC I have a button which opens another UC with three buttons to select any of three difficulty levels. Whenever I click any of these buttons I open a UC with a textbox in it. To this TextBox I am going to use a method to generate different questions. The questions are supposed to differ in difficulty level, so I am assigning a value to a variable depending on what difficulty the user selects and in my method it checks for what difficulty is chosen and is to generate code from that. And then I have a "next" button which generates a new question.

My problem is:
The textbox is to be assigned a question upon load. So when any of the three difficulty buttons is pressed, a question is generated to the textbox when the UC is freshly opened. But it doesn't. I have to press the "Next" button for it to generate a question. So how can I do this upon the load of a usercontrol?

It seems is as if the UserControl is "static" cause it loads whenever i just start the program (tested this by running a MessageBox in the initializecomponent), cause else I could've done

```
This.TextBox1.Text = Class1.GenerateQuestion();
```

in the InitializeComponent in my UC right? But the UserControl is loaded right away when I start the program so I can't do that. How do I solve the problem? Been sitting with this for some days now.

[DifficultyUC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYBPz.png)

[QuestionsUC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Om0.png)

Here is all my code (whole project): ufile.io/1d08w

Comment: You need to show your code

Comment: The issue is not to do with whether it is static, as this would allow you to change the text. Static does not mean unchangeable. - There is a problem in your code, and without seeing it, it is difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks guys. Here it is https://ufile.io/1d08w